# Creating New Values for Column from Vector of Differences

Tags: r, vector, subtraction

So I have a data frame of dates and a response column and I have a vector of differences to show the change over time for a set of new values I want to add to the response column. How can I do some sort of matrix subtraction to take the values from the vector and difference them from the existing values in the column to get new values?

The data frame is set up like this:

```
data <- data.frame(seq(from = 2001, to = 2020, 1))
data$y <- (runif(20, 1, 10))
data$y[11:20] <- NA
colnames(data)[1] <- "Year"
```

the vector of differences looks like this:

```
vector <- runif(10, -1, 1)
```

So the desired output would look like this:

```
Year    y
2011    y10+vector1 = y11
2012    y11+vector2 = y12
2013    y12+vector3 = y13
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use the `cumsum`function:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(seq(2001, 2020, 1))
data$y <- (runif(20, 1, 10))
data$y[11:20] <- NA
colnames(data)[1] <- "Year" 

myvector <- runif(10, -1, 1)
data$y[11:20] <- data$y[10] + cumsum(myvector)
```

Also, it is good practice to set a random seed (with `set.seed`) when working with random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The following gets the cumulative sum of your vector of responses, but starting with the value of y in 2010

```
responses <- c(data$y[data$Year == 2010], vector)

new_data <- data.frame(year = 2010:2020,
                       y = cumsum(responses))

   year        y
1  2010 3.263457
2  2011 2.891375
3  2012 3.567775
4  2013 4.330650
5  2014 4.972721
6  2015 5.008574
7  2016 5.306517
8  2017 5.304533
9  2018 5.066068
10 2019 4.688454
11 2020 4.851382
```